# Which web browser is most secure?

Tags: security, browser

I have been looking about the pros and cons of browsers specifically for security property. Please share if you know which browser is more secure than others and why it is so.

Comment: Too many variable. Which OS, which web server, what the code does, how secure is the code. You can have a 64 character, super strong password, and then write on a post it note and stick it on your monitor...

Answer (score 2):

Each browser have different security features, vulnerability, maybe even NSA backdoors for some of them, at some point in time but... http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/view/33645/there-is-no-single-most-secure-browser/

You might want to look here for additional insight : http://slashdot.org/story/13/06/23/0317243/ask-slashdot-most-secure-browser-in-an-age-of-surveillance

Answer (score 0):

There is not web browser that is more secure than other in big margin, reason being is that most todays browsers use at most same standard. For example, usage of javascripts is allowed or disabled by default, tracking and sharing, your ip... Beacause this question does not have proper answer, here is example how to make web browser secure as much as possible if needed:

In this example I will use Mozilla Firefox.

First step is disabling javascripts in web browser (manually or by implementing some plugin to do that, for example "NoScript")

Disabling javascripts will disable viewing web pages properly or using them beacause almost any website today use javascripts. But we talk now about security.

Second step should be disabling tracking and sharing again, manually or by some plugin.

Third should be usage of some proxy server to hide your ip.

There is to many different things that could be done, also note again, javascripts, that are required for proper displaying page content and proper interaction with them on almost all modern websites, but can be big security hole, for example, session hijacking, forcing browser to get your geolocation and to many other things...

My reccomendation is to see first exactly, what you would like to protect, and then search on google how to do that.